# NSHTTPCookieStorage deleteCookie does'nt work in ios6?

Tags: ios, ios6, nshttpcookie

my problem that the below code:

```
 [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] deleteCookie:cookie];
```

works fine with ios 5 but with ios6 cookies are not deleted and the web view still uses the same cookies setted before.

Does anyone has an idea about this issue?

**Update**

after killing the app , it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with this method which i used to make authentication:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge{


       [[challenge sender] useCredential:[NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:Username password:Password persistence:CredentialsPresistance]


forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
}
```

the "persistence" ought to be equal to NSURLCredentialPersistenceNone  in ios6 only.

This **solved** my problem.